# Java cannot call addAll() to add arraylist of type subclass to an arraylist of type <? extends baseClass>

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have two classes, a superclass, and a child class inheriting the superclass. I want to combine two array lists into one. The two arraylists have different types. One is a superclass list the other is a subclass.

These are my three lists:

```
public ArrayList<subClass> list1;
public ArrayList<superClass> list2;

public ArrayList<? extends superClass> combined; // so this accepts all subclasses as well
```

I am then trying to accomplish the below:

```
combined.addAll(list1);
combined.addAll(list2);
```

The compiler is saying:

```
addAll in arrayList cannot be applied to list1
addAll in arrayList cannot be applied to list2
```

but: `combined = list1;` gives no error. With the equals sign though I cannot combine the two lists.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: As you said yourself, you can do `combined = list1`. So after that, if you could do `combined.addAll(list2)`, then your `list1` now has objects that aren't necessarily instances of `subClass`, meaning type guarantees on `list1` break. Which is why this is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

```
public ArrayList<? extends superClass> combined
```

Doesn't mean "this accepts all subclasses as well". It means you can assign to that variable an `ArrayList<superClass>` or an `ArrayList<subClass>` or an `ArrayList<someOtherSubClass>`, etc...

Therefore you can't assign to it the elements of `list1` or `list2`, since the compiler doesn't know which `ArrayList<? extends superClass>` will be assigned to that variable).

For example, if you initialized that variable with:

```
public ArrayList<? extends superClass> combined = new ArrayList<subClass2>();
```

You shouldn't be able to add to that `List` instances of type `subClass`.

You could use:

```
public ArrayList<superClass> combined
```

instead. Now you can add to that `ArrayList` all elements of type `superClass` or any sub-class of it.

Comment: but this way I cannot then call subclass methods on the elements of list 1 in `combined` right?

Comment: @user7331538 that's correct. But that would have been the behavior with your original definition of `combined` too.

Comment: is there a way that I can combine these while still retaining their class and method of subclasses? (other than using is instanceOf)